# Jest - mockReturnValue

Tags: jestjs

I have a function which I'm trying to add unit tests for.

**Function**

```js
        async getStuff() {
           const { foo } = this.props.data;
           const { bar } = this.state;
           const { bazz } = this.props;

           const { x, y } = await helpers.getStuffFromServer(foo, bar, bazz);

           this.setState({ x, y });
        }
```

**Test**

```js
        it('should get stuff & set state', async() => {
           const returnObject = {
               x: dummyData.x,
               y: dummyData.y
           };
           getStuff.mockReturnValue(() => returnObject);
           const fakeBazz = jest.fn();
           const wrapper = setup({ bazz: fakeBazz });
           wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
           await expect(getStuff).toBeCalledWith(dummyData.foo, bar, fakeBazz);
           console.log(wrapper.state());
    });
```

My `expect` assertion works and correct asserts that `getStuff` was called with the correct values. But `getStuff` returns 2 x objects `x` & `y` - which it uses to `setState`. I've tried to mock the return value of `getStuff`, but these mocked return values are not being set in state.

Am I using `mockReturnValue` correctly?

Comment: try to call wrapper.update() before checking the state

Comment: @VivekN - no joy. my state remains unchanged

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't you set it on the mock function:

```js
    fakeBazz.mockReturnValue(returnObject);
```

See: https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c